# CGContextRef/Objective C to CGContext/Swift confusion

Tags: objective-c, swift, cgcontext, cgcontextref

I have a base class, written in objective C which for many reasons, is used to get the CGContext when a sub-class needs to draw in drawRect.

```
-(CGContextRef)fetchContext
{
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    return context;
}
```

I now a sub-class written in Swift which needs to do some drawing, so is asking for the CGContext in super....

```
    override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
        // Drawing code
        let bounds = self.bounds;

        let context:CGContextRef = self.fetchContext();

        CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 5.0);
        CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, UIColor.redColor().CGColor );

        CGContextBeginPath(context);

        CGContextMoveToPoint(context, 0, 0);
        CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, bounds.size.width, 0);
        CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, bounds.size.width, bounds.size.height);
        CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, 0, bounds.size.height);
        CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, 0, 0);

        CGContextStrokePath(context);

        super.drawRect( rect );
    }
```

The problem lies in the line

```
    let context:CGContextRef = self.fetchContext();
```

This is not compiling with the error:

```
'Unmanaged<CGContext>' is not convertible to 'CGContextRef'
```

I'm confused as to why this is. A CGContext is aliased to a CGContextRef in Swift, so I would have thought this would work.

Can someone explain/help?

Comment: Why don't you just skip the obj-c and directly assign like this: `let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()`

Comment: As explained in the answers to the "duplicate", you can *either* annotate the Objective-C function: `-(CGContextRef)fetchContext CF_RETURNS_NOT_RETAINED;` *or* write `self.fetchContext().takeUnretainedValue()` in the Swift code.

Comment: Thanks.  That explains it.